# Raw green onions are spicy, but heated green onions are sweet. Why is this?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

Raw green onions are spicy, but heated green onions are sweet. Why is this? More specifically; what change in the raw green onion's organic chemicals makes it no longer spicy when the green onions are slightly burnt, and is there some chemical change in the burnt green onions that also make it sweeter, or is it just the removal of the spicy compound?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Onions [caramelize](https://food52.com/blog/27932-the-right-way-to-caramelize-onions), becoming sweet as various complex [saccharides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbohydrate) are broken down to more "tasty" sugars. For instance, in onions, green (scallions), yellow, red or other, chains of fructose are broken into fructose monomer and dissolved in the onion's water (~90% by mass), making the sweet taste accessible to the taste buds. Caramelizing also produces *many* complex changes in other chemicals, too.

In addition, [onion and its relatives contain](https://www.compoundchem.com/2014/01/22/the-chemistry-of-an-onion/) strong-tasting, strong-smelling, and even [lachrymatory](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lachrymatory) compounds, such as [syn-propanethial S-oxide](https://www.acs.org/molecule-of-the-week/archive/p/syn-propanethial-s-oxide.html). Since these are volatile and [not too stable](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/12/12/16060), caramelizing onions for half and hour or more destroys or evaporates them, leaving the pure melt-in-the-mouth caramelized onions.

<sub>*Sorry, my mouth is watering and I must leave to get a napkin...*</sub>

Comment: I have authentically been drawn to emotional tears at the smell of frying and caramelizing onions. Well written and useful answer, danke!

Comment: (+1) And garlic is an **allicin wonderland**, as a colleague used to say!

Comment: This is a wonderful answer, and it is a delight to know that mere LLMs (such as ChatGPT) cannot threaten the intellectual capacity of human scientists and lifelong learners. Thank you so much!